# Random split a PyTorch dataset of type TensorDataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a custom dataset loaded into python in numpy: (20640x8) matrix of inputs, (20640x1) vector of labels.

I am trying to prepare the data for training in a PyTorch machine learning model, which requires a training set and test set split. In my attempt, the `random_split()` function reports an error:

> TypeError: randperm() received an invalid combination of arguments.

I couldn't figure out how to split the dataset. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, random_split

x_numpy = # (20640x8) matrix of floats
y_numpy = # (20640x1) vector of floats
x = torch.from_numpy(x_numpy.astype(np.float32))
y = torch.from_numpy(y_numpy.astype(np.float32))
dataset = TensorDataset(x, y)
trainSet, testSet = random_split(dataset, [0.6*len(dataset), 0.4*len(dataset)])
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The dataset length must be integers:

```
>>> split = int(0.6*len(dataset))
>>> trainSet, testSet = random_split(dataset, [split, len(dataset)-split])
```